# Get featured images from custom taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress

Oke, first of I downloaded [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/). This enables me to give my custom taxonomy terms an image. This works great. But the way my theme is setup and the way the plugin wants to work, isn't for me.

I only want the images to show in the place where I say it should. That's why I used terms (categories). Because then I can use this code:

```
<?php
//list terms in a given taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'our_team';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

That only shows the names of the team members when you activated them (checked the box) in the post, and not in other places.

Now I would like to be able to use a similar code but for the featured images. The plugin uses this code to get the thumbnails.

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
    'before'       => '<div class="my-custom-class-name">',
    'after'        => '</div>',
    'before_image' => '<span>',
    'after_image'  => '</span>',
    'image_size'   => 'detail',
    'post_id'      => 15,
    'taxonomy'     => 'our_team',
) );
```

Does anyone know how to "merge" these two codes together and generate an image only if I checked the box in the custom post type. Or knows another way to do this?

** UPDATE **
Ok, getting somewhere. The code is now only displayed where I want it. With the help of Rohit Kishore! Thanks! Here is the working code:

```
<div class="teamleden over-ons-ul">
          <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'our_team' ); 
                print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
                            'before'       => '<div class="our-team">',
                            'after'        => '</div>',
                            'before_image' => '<span>',
                            'after_image'  => '</span>',
                            'image_size'   => 'detail',
                            'taxonomy'     => 'our_team',
                        ) );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'our_team' );
                    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                    continue;


                } 
            ?>
    </div>
```

The `print` code had to be before the foreach part...

Comment: why you have used post_id.
Do you need to fetch terms for certain post?

Comment: Let me update the code. Im getting some where here...

Comment: How much terms are there in `our_team` taxanomy?

Comment: 10 that's the thing... I got team member 1, 2, 3, 4 .... 9, 10. If I add another one it'll probably loop 11 times...

Comment: okay than run the `print apply_filters` after the `foreach` loop. And do you also want to display terms from `our_team` taxonomy or just image?

Comment: Ill update code again. To see if I did it correct. With this code it still shows 10 terms/items. I just want the images... and the link to the correct page (permalink).

Comment: Actually I didn't get you. What exactly do you want. Do you want to show all `terms` or just the image or what?

Comment: Well I just want the images to show up. But I got it to work :) Thanks to your help!